# PHP when sending data (table name) via a Submit button always shows the last table created

Tags: php, html, mysql

So, im a little new to php and i need to send a table name to another php file this is the code i already have:

```
<form action="clases.php" method="GET">

        <?php
         $result= mysql_query('SHOW TABLES', $conn) or die ('cannot show tables');
    while($tablename = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $a=0;
        $table = $tablename[$a];




       echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table">';
       echo '<tr>';


        echo '<td>',$table,'<input type="hidden" name="Class" value="' . $table . '" />';
        echo '</td>';
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='Entrar' value='Enter'></td>";
        echo "<td><input type='submit' name='Eliminar' value='Delete'></td>";
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</table><br />';
        ++$a;
      }
        ?>
</form>
```

Right now i just need the Enter button working, when i submit it i should send to another php file with just:

```
<?php $classname = $_GET['Class']; echo $classname; ?>
```

But it always gives me the last table i created, so if a have 3 tables created

- Table A
- Table B
- Table C

the $classname always shows "Table C".

Sorry about the english, its not my first lenguaje.

Comment: You are executing in the loop. Move you table tags (beginning and ending) out of the loop. You can loop through the rows, thats no problem at all.

Comment: Oh... Thanks! ill try it, now i feel dumb hahaha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the code is executed in a loop. By the time you press enter the loop is complete and the only available table is the last one created which it table C.You can use an array of tables to store every table string created.Retrieve it and then attach an event